# Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (72)

Tags: node.js, sass

I'm using macOS Catalina 10.15.3.

I'm generating thumbnail images with this [Jekyll theme](https://github.com/janczizikow/sleek), and when I enter `gulp img`, that error occurs.

```
Requiring external module babel-register
~/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:13
      throw new Error(errors.unsupportedEnvironment());
      ^

Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (72)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.7.1
    at module.exports (~/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:13:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (~/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1177:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (~/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:900:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (~/node_modules/gulp-sass/index.js:187:21)
```

I tried everything, like `npm install`, `npm uninstall`, `npm rebuild node-sass`, and so on, but I don't know why the error appears.

Comment: What version of node are you running? `node --version` - it looks like you're running an outdated version of Node Sass... The error message you are getting points to a link for `v4.7.1` - but [`v4.13.1`](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.13.1) is the newest release...Also, [have a look at other issues](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+does+not+yet+support+your+current+environment) that people have filed for the same error, as they offer resolutions.

Comment: @MattOestreich When I run `node --version`, it says that I'm currently using `v12.16.1` now.

Comment: Looks like it may be an issue with one of the dependencies you are using.. [See here](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2849#issuecomment-586131767)

Comment: @MattOestreich How can I find the old dependencies and upgrade them?

Comment: Search your `node_modules` via a file search......

Comment: @MattOestreich Should I look over `package.json` or the folder named `node_modules` at the root of the project?

Comment: The folder called `node_modules`.

Comment: I have the same problem ... with a Vue application ... on MacOS 10.15.5

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. For me it helped to reinstall NodeJs (in my case 14.15.1 LTS) and then the already mentioned command:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Comment: Good job my bro.

Comment: @Samuel,I hope my answer could help you. If it is so, you could set my answer as correct. Thx

Comment: What would be the yarn equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Tried to rebuild node-sass after the most recent Mac OS update using other answers. Switching to Dart Sass was my last resort after update node, npm, reinstalling all packages and rebuilding node-sass.

node-sass is deprecated in favor of dart sass:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass

https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass

After uninstalling node-sass and installing sass, I still get warnings when doing yarn build, but my react project is building again.

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Charles Letcher's response above, I wanted to add that the npm sass version also works for those on ARM/M1 architecture.

I took my existing Gulp project and installed sass on Node v14 and Node v16. Once this happened, my project launched flawlessly.